# How to perform reflection call to a method carries String, String, String... as parameters?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I'm facing an issue where I need to use reflection call to invoke method which carries parameters String, String, String... . My code is as below

```
public void testArrayParams(String first, String second, String... strings) {

    System.out.println("First: " + first);
    System.out.println("Second: " + second);

    System.out.println("Size of String... strings: " + strings.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i ++) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + strings[i]);
    }

}
```

And below is the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
    //dummy.testArrayParams("Hello", "World", "This is ", "passed in ", "format String... strings.");

    String[] params = {"Hello", "World", "This is ", "passed in ", "format String... strings."};
    String method = "testArrayParams";

    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.bt.testafix.utils.Dummy");
        Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();

        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(method)) {
                //m.invoke(clazz, (Object[]) params);
                m.invoke(clazz, new Object[]{params});
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It throws below exception when I run the code

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

I have tried change to `m.invoke(clazz, (Object[]) params);`, which is a casting but still giving the same exception. Any idea I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Change the code from `m.invoke(clazz, new Object[]{params});` to `m.invoke(dummy, params);`
The first parameter should be the instance of the class on which you wish to invoke the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the parameter information that `Method` instance gives you, you'll find that the last parameter is a `String[]` parameter, because varargs are implemented in Java as an array parameter.

So your `params` should reflect that:

```
Object[] params = {
    "Hello",
    "World",
    new String[] {
        "This is ",
        "passed in ",
        "format String... strings."
    }
};
```

Separately, two problems with your `invoke` call:

1. The method isn't a method on `clazz`, you'll need an instance (since it's an instance method). E.g., `clazz.newInstance()` or similar.
2. You've used `new Object[]{params}`, which means you're passing a *single* argument to the method. It expects three.

So:

```
m.invoke(clazz.newInstance(), params);
```

[**Working live copy**](https://ideone.com/HUbh7i)

Comment: Thanks dude, you resolved my issue. It's working fine now.

Comment: But I have a question here. I tried run this line of code - dummy.testArrayParams("Hello", "World", "This is ", "passed in ", "format String... strings."); it's working fine. I do not need to explicitly declare array of String like you mentioned. Why is it like that?

Comment: @chris: The compiler handles varargs for you when you use the method explicitly like that. But when you use reflection, you have to handle the varargs yourself (by providing the array for the varargs parameter).

Answer (score 0):

For static method, the first argument to invoke should be null, for non-static methods, it should be an instance of the declaring class (in neither case should it be the class itself.)